# Translation of partie stable

Tags: traduction, mathématiques

I'm looking for the translation of the mathematical term **Partie stable**.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: [Don't ask: How to translate a French expression into another language.](https://french.stackexchange.com/tour)

Answer (score 2):

*Partie* means "subset."

The term *partie stable* would be translated as "stable subset."

Or: "A subset stable under a function *f* [or closed under an operation *X*]."

Let f be a mapping from a set E to itself, and let S be a subset of E. The subset S is said to be *stable* under f if f(S) is contained in S.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution (+1). The term is meant to be used in algebraic structures: Partie stable d’un loi de composition intern.

Comment: Partie stable *pour* une loi de composition interne. The subset is stable *for* the operation, not *of* the operation.

Comment: @jlliagre The distinction between asking what something means and asking how to translate it is not always clear-cut. The injunction not to ask for translations makes the most sense when applied to a text of some length rather than to an isolated expression.

Comment: The distinction is sometimes not clear-cut but the phrasing used here is not ambiguous. Moreover, the site rule explicitly states *a French expression* so doesn't restrict itself to lengthier text. The question should then be either closed or rephrased to comply with FSE rules.

Comment: All right. I'm always fascinated by the fact that SE sites expend so much energy on these kinds of things.

Comment: I understand and often share your frustration but we are all supposed to follow the rules and these rules can be discussed in Meta. By the way, you might want to state *partie* means *sous-ensemble* in your reply.

Comment: @Toto I proposed an edit of the question so that it would comply with site rules. I also see that you voted to close the question. I'm curious as to why one would vote to close a question but also reject an edit that would make the question compliant with the site rules.